# WSO2 Claims for First name

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In WSO2 IS admin console, we are trying to set the user claims for a service provider under 'Claim Configuration'.

We selected the Claim mapping Dialect as 'Define Custom Claim Dialect' and added Local claims as :

- http://wso2.org/claims/givenname
- http://wso2.org/claims/lastname
- http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress

But when we perform a curl with `/oauth2/userinfo`, it just gives us last name and email. But first name is not being returned.

Returned User Info:

```
{"sub":"abc@carbon.super","family_name":"abcFN","email":"abc@abc.com"}
```

Any pointers for the issue will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually an error in the mapping of the given name attribute between the oidc claim and the wso2 claim :

In the management console, go to Home > Identity > Claims > List > claim.view
Click on http://wso2.org/oidc/claim in the Available Claims Dialect list

Change the mapping for given_name to Mapped Local Claim : http://wso2.org/claims/givenname

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the first name through user info endpoint,you should have an OIDC claim mapping with http://wso2.org/claims/givenname.

Could you please check whether your given_name claim under oidc dialect has a mapping with http://wso2.org/claims/givenname.